# Metric Space Limit Question showing limit continuity with open sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

The question I've been presented is for a metric space $(M,d)$ and $(x_n) $ being a sequence of elements in M 
Show $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x_0$$ iff for all open sets $A \subseteq M$ with $x_0 \in A$ there is an $N(A) \in (Naturals)$ such that $x_n \in A, \forall n \geq N(A)$,

This type of iff statement is well aboe anything else we've had to prove so far.  My initial thoughts were to assume the limit of $x_n$ does not equal $x_0$ for the first side of the statement but from there I've tried toying with the idea of maybe assuming A isn't open but I'm somewhat stumpoed.

Any help on where to start would be super appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if part. For open $A$ that $x_{0}\in A$, since $\{B_{\epsilon}(x_{0}): \epsilon>0\}$ is a local basis, then there exists some $\epsilon_{0}>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon_{0}}(x_{0})\subseteq A$. Now $x_{n}\rightarrow x_{0}$, so there exists some $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $d(x_{n},x_{0})<\epsilon_{0}$, the latter means that $x_{n}\in B_{\epsilon_{0}}(x_{0})$, so $x_{n}\in A$ eventually.

The if part is easy.

Comment: Oh ok.  Doing the second part of the statement shouldn't be too bad then.  My thoughts would be to consider a ball $B(x, \epsilon)$ and following the quantifies would get back to $lim x_n \to x_0$ where $\epsilon > 0$ *

Comment: Yes, just to consider the open set $B_{\epsilon}(x_{0})$ then it goes through.